# WooCommerce product id as permalink

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, permalinks, links, slug

Currently, the WooCommerce product permalinks is '/product/shoes-3' , '/product/cup-12' etc.

How to change product permalinks to only be like /p/product_ID , for example '/p/1122' without using any plugins?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there is a good plugin to do this with ease. 'Permalinks Customizer' https://wordpress.org/plugins/permalinks-customizer/